# Get all comments made by user Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there any way to get all comments created by the user..

user_id is not indexable in comment table rather object_id...

```
SELECT id, text, time, fromid FROM comment WHERE object_id='10151309718465667'
```

And stream table doesn't return any type:257(comment created)

```
SELECT type, object_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
```

Seems there's noway to get user comments directly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below query:

```
SELECT id, text, time, fromid FROM comment 
WHERE post_id in 
    (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN
        (SELECT filter_key from stream_filter where uid = me())) 
and fromid = me() limit 500
```

It does not get all the comments but you will get the comments the user did on his/her wall